# Select and wrap two divs with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to wrap divs in a 'row' wrapper, so that there are two divs in each.

My code looks like this:

```
<div id="content" class="center cutepicscontainer cf">
  <div class="product cf">product 1</div>
  <div class="product cf">product 2</div>
  <div class="product cf">product 3</div>
  <div class="product cf">product 4</div>
</div>
```

And I would like my products to be sorted like this:

```
<div id="content" class="center cutepicscontainer cf">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="product cf">product 1</div>
    <div class="product cf">product 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="product cf">product 3</div>
    <div class="product cf">product 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I searched and found a piece of jquery code, but this doesn't work exactly like I want.

```
 $('.cutepicscontainer .product').each(function(){
        $(this).next().andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="row"/>');
    });
```

This is the outcome : https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jqww.png

Thanks in advance!

Victor

**EDIT** added .product:even, now it works!

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gohqqx9g/

Comment: That's weird.. http://jsfiddle.net/74u22gz7/ This is a more detailed view of my code. @j08691

Comment: You didn't add jquery on this fiddle, are you missing jquery also on your webpage?

Comment: @mathf, Sorry, Never really used jsfiddle before. It works in the fiddle now too, but not on my actual website. Here is a screenshot of my code (local server). http://i.imgur.com/iQNjXpU.png

Comment: Can you check your js console if there are any errors?

Comment: You need to include a library in your `<head>`. You can either download the library and reference it like you would any other script, or you can use google's library (suggested as it will usually run faster since host machines have likely visited other pages with google jquery library in `<head>` tag). So for the latter option include this in your `<head>` before you call your scripts:` <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I can't find it in your code, I must be blind, what row number?

Comment: @ctwheels here you go :-) http://i.imgur.com/LCYR5Ho.png

Comment: My apologies, thank you. Is that line placed before the code that is giving you a tough time?

Comment: @ctwheels Yes indeed, jquery is included in <head>, and the code that is giving me a hard time is a further down towards the end of <body>

Comment: @VictorVaughn I just looked at the fiddle you posted, you're missing semicolons in your code (at the end and inside the function). Use this:`$('#content .product:even').each(function(){
  $(this).next().addBack().wrapAll('<div class="row"/>');
});` see if it works? You were missing the following semicolons `$('#content .product:even').each(function(){
  $(this).next().addBack().wrapAll('<div class="row"/>')` HERE ;
`})` HERE ;

Comment: hey @ctwheels, I updated my code to:

    $('#content .product:even').each(function(){
         $(this).next().addBack().wrapAll('<div class="row"/>');
  }); and nothing changed, still doesn't work I'm afraid :(

Comment: Test your site using the `<script>...</script>` tag I included above to link to Google's JQuery library, and comment your library out, see if it changes anything?

Comment: @ctwheels To be honest, I am using Concrete5 and I wouldn't know how to change the link. Doubt it would make any difference. If i remove the 'wrapping' code that is giving me trouble though, the 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function' error is gone.

Comment: I think it doesn't recognize .each(), if you add the script I included above in your `<head>` and leave the rest the same, what happens?

Comment: I added the code in <head>, and nothing changed. sorry!

Comment: Then I'm not exactly sure, sorry. You can start a bounty, maybe someone will be able to figure this out.

Comment: Not enough reputation for that I'm afraid :-(

Comment: @ctwheels this code is something I tried earlier: and it sort of works: $(".cutepicscontainer .product").each(function() {
  $(this).next(".product").andSelf().wrapAll("<div class='form-element-wrapper' />")
 }); but this is the outcome: http://i.imgur.com/f1yFO9I.png  -- Also, the uncaught typeError is gone!

Comment: Please see my edit of the original post. I fixed it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.cutepicscontainer .product:even').each(function(){
        $(this).next().andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="row cf"/>');
    });
```

This works!